# jQuery - stop animation in progress (fadeOut) and show again when mouse enters/leaves quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a <div> that when hovered over, will show some text. When the mouse leaves, the text fades out. However, if the mouse enters the <div> again before the `fadeOut` is complete, the text never shows again.

I am aware of `hoverintent`, but I'd prefer not to use it because of the slight perceived delay it gives to the `mouseEnter/mouseLeave` events.

Is there no way that, upon `mouseEnter`, it simply clears the `fadeOut` and shows the text again?

My current attempt using timeouts:

```
var timeouts = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wrapper').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeouts['test_hover']);
    $('#text').show();
  }, function(){
    timeouts['test_hover'] = setTimeout(function(){
      $('#text').fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/upotuw/5

video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RLrz1bEQuU

--

EDIT: Issue was needing to pass both parameters to the `stop()` function: `stop(true,true)`

Final working code is as follows:

```
var timeouts = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wrapper').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeouts['test_hover']);
    $('#text').stop(true,true).show();
  }, function(){
    timeouts['test_hover'] = setTimeout(function(){
      $('#text').fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/upotuw/7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to look into the JQuery `stop()` function:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Ah. I had a 'stop' on there before, but neglected to pass both variables as true. `stop(true,true)` worked.