# JS image doesnt stop when i release the arrow key

Tags: javascript, html

so i'm trying to make this HTML game with javascript but the head keeps moving a little if i hold down the key for over a second.
How can i make it that when i remove finger from the arrow key that it stops?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
            // Left arrow key pressed
            case 37:
                $('#char').animate({
                    left: "-=10px"
                }, '1000ms');
                break;
                // Up Arrow Pressed
            case 38:
                // Put our code here
                $('#char').animate({
                    top: "-=10px"
                }, '1000ms');
                break;
                // Right Arrow Pressed
            case 39:
                // Put our code here
                $('#char').animate({
                    left: "+=10px"
                }, '1000ms');
                break;
                // Down Arrow Pressed
            case 40:
                // Put our code here
                $('#char').animate({
                    top: "+=10px"
                }, '1000ms');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - stop animation in progress (fadeOut) and show again when mouse enters/leaves quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175755/jquery-stop-animation-in-progress-fadeout-and-show-again-when-mouse-enters-l)

Comment: im trying to say that when i stop pressing keyboard arrow not cursor

Comment: Sure, so combine the `.stop()` function from the linked question with using a `keyup` event handler and you're golden.

Comment: im kinda new to coding so im sry for asking but where do i add the keyup and .stop?

Comment: Keyup: `$(document).keyup(function(key) { /* insert your code here */ })`. For stop: `$('#char').stop()`. You can read about all kinds of jQuery functions [at their website](http://api.jquery.com/). They usually provide pretty good examples of how to use them.

Comment: thank you for showin.last question,do you know a good website or something where i can learn coding for game development? i know some HTML CSS and the basics of JS.i learned it all from codecademy.

Comment: There's lots of tutorials and lots to learn. A good place to start would be [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Workflows/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript) You'll learn how to make your own Breakout style game (a fantastic beginner project) and it only gets better from there.

Comment: okay,youre so awesome for helping me out!

Comment: Don't trigger movement directly from the key event handlers. Use keydown and keyup handlers to maintain a state table of which keys are down at any given moment, then separate to that create a "game loop" with setTimeout() or requestAnimationFrame() - do the animations from within the game loop. (I know that explanation is too vague to actually code from, but google "JavaScript game loop" and you'll find detailed tutorials. The Breakout tutorial above uses a very simple version of this.)